# How to mark locations retreived from firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-cloud-firestore, location

I'm trying to developing an app with google Maps functionalities. I want to mark location data retrieved from firestore in google Maps. This is my firebase database.
[image]

I tried all the ways. Nothing seems to be work. Anyone help me to do this.
Below is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:klndrive/sharedPreferences/sharedPreferences.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:search_map_place/search_map_place.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';


class FindaRide extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FindaRideState createState() => _FindaRideState();
}

class _FindaRideState extends State<FindaRide> {

  //Google map variables
  Position position;
  bool mapToggle = false;



  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  double _originLatitude, _originLongitude;
  LatLng placeCords, startCords, endCords;
  double _destLatitude, _destLongitude;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  Map<PolylineId, Polyline> polylines = {};
  PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];

  String mapStyle;



  //In app necessary variables
  final format = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
  DateTime dateTime;
  final Color darkBlueColor = Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 48, 1.0);

  //Search/Create variables
  String from = "";
  String to = "";

  LatLng pickUpPoint;
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  List<LatLng> randPoints = new List<LatLng>();
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  List<String> selectedPoints = new List<String>();

  //booleans for widgets' visibility
  bool showStartingScreen = true;
  bool isTouchable = false;

  void _currentLocation() async {

    _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
      CameraPosition(
        bearing: 0,
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        zoom: 17.0,
      ),
    ));
  }

  void getCurrentPosition() async{
    Position currentPosition = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      position = currentPosition;
      mapToggle = true;
      print(position);

      //circle around my location


    });



    CollectionReference location = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location');
    // FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    // String uid = _auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
    final coordinated = new Coordinates(position.latitude,position.longitude);
    var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinated);
    var firstAddress = address.first;

    location.add({
      'username': await MySharedPreferences.instance.getStringValue("userName"),
      'lattitude': position.latitude,
      'longitude': position.longitude,
      'address': firstAddress.addressLine,
      'postalcode': firstAddress.postalCode,
      'locality': firstAddress.locality,
    });

    print(await MySharedPreferences.instance.getStringValue("userName"));
    print(position.latitude);
    print(position.longitude);
    print(firstAddress.addressLine);
    print(firstAddress.postalCode);
    print(firstAddress.locality);

    //getting markers from firestore



  }



  @override
  void initState() {

    getCurrentPosition();

    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      getMarkerData();
    });
  }

  void initMarker(specify, specifyID) async {
    var markerIdval = specifyID;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdval);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId : markerId,
      position: LatLng(double.parse(specify['lattitude']), double.parse(specify['longitude'].toDouble())),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: specify['username'],snippet: specify['address']),


    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  getMarkerData() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').get().then((myLocData){
      if(myLocData.docs.isNotEmpty){
        for(int i=0;i<myLocData.docs.length;i++){
            initMarker(myLocData.docs[i].data, myLocData.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }



  Set<Marker> getMarker(){
    return <Marker>[
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("one"),
        position: LatLng(9.880892,78.112317),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title:"one"),


      )
    ].toSet();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return homeScaffold();
  }

  Widget homeScaffold() {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,


      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          mapToggle ? _googleMap(context) : Center(child: Text('Loading...',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),),
          _startingScreen(showStartingScreen),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }




  Widget _startingScreen(bool isVisible) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: isVisible,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 250.0,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                _fillField("From: ", Colors.blue, 10.0, BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue
    )),
                _fillField("To: ", Colors.red, 10.0, BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
    BitmapDescriptor.hueRed)),
                _dateField(),
              ],

            ),
          ),
          _customButton(Alignment.bottomRight, 145.0, Icons.my_location, "Me",
              _onLocationPressed),
          _customButton(Alignment.bottomRight, 80.0, Icons.search, "Search",
              _onSearchPressed),
          _customButton(Alignment.bottomRight, 15.0, Icons.add, "Create",
              _onCreatePressed),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Align _fillField(String str, Color clr, double top, BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: top),
        child: SearchMapPlaceWidget(
          language: 'en',
          hasClearButton: true,
          placeType: PlaceType.address,
          apiKey: _googleAPiKey,
          placeholder: str,
          icon: IconData(0xe55f, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons'),
          iconColor: clr,
          // The position used to give better recommendations. In this case we are using the user position
          location: LatLng(37.9931036, 23.7301123),
          radius: 30000,
          onSelected: (Place place) async {
            final geolocation = await place.geolocation;
            _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(geolocation.coordinates));
            _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(geolocation.bounds, 0));

            _clearPolylines();

            if(str=="From: "){
              from = place.description;
              _addMarker(geolocation.coordinates, place.placeId, bitmapDescriptor, place.description);
              _originLatitude = placeCords.latitude;
              _originLongitude = placeCords.longitude;
              startCords = placeCords;
              setState(() {

              });
            }

            if(str=="To: "){
              to = place.description;
              _addMarker(geolocation.coordinates, place.placeId, bitmapDescriptor, place.description);
              _destLatitude = placeCords.latitude;
              _destLongitude = placeCords.longitude;
              endCords = placeCords;
            }

            if(_originLongitude!= null && _originLatitude != null && _destLongitude != null && _destLatitude != null)
              _getPolyline("demo");

          },

        )
      ),

    );
  }





  Align _dateField() {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0),
            child: DateTimeField(
              format: format,
              onChanged: (DateTime dt) {
                dateTime = dt;
              },
              resetIcon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.black,),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                  ),
                  //suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today, color: Colors.black,),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  labelText: "Date: ",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black
                  )
              ),
              onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
                final date = await showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    firstDate: DateTime.now(),
                    initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
                if (date != null) {
                  final time = await showTimePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialTime:
                    TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
                  );
                  return DateTimeField.combine(date, time);
                } else {
                  return currentValue;
                }
              },
            )));
  } //dateField

  Widget _customButton(Alignment alignment, double bottom, IconData icon,
      String label, Function onPressed) {
    return Align(
      alignment: alignment,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            right: 10.0, bottom: bottom, left: 10.0, top: 10.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 50.0,
          width: 120.0,
          child: ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: Icon(icon),
            label: Text(label),
            onPressed: () {
              onPressed();
            },
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.blue,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              ),

            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //the method called when the user presses the search button
  _onSearchPressed() async {
    print('search button pressed');
    if (_areFieldsFilled()) {

    }
  } //onSearchPressed


  //the method called when the user presses the create button
  _onCreatePressed() {
    print("on create pressed");
    if (_areFieldsFilled()) {

    }
  } //onCreatePressed

  _onLocationPressed(){
    _currentLocation();
  }

  bool _areFieldsFilled() {
    if (from == "") {
      _showToast("Missing 'From' field!");
      return false;
    }
    if (to == "") {
      _showToast("Missing 'To' field!");
      return false;
    }
    if (dateTime == null) {
      _showToast("Missing 'Date' field!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  _showToast(String message) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    );
  }


  Widget _googleMap(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .height,
      width: MediaQuery
          .of(context)
          .size
          .width,
      child: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target:  LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude),
            zoom: 20,
        ),
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
        compassEnabled: false,
        scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polylines.values),
        onTap: _onMapTap,

      ),
    );
  }


  void _onMapTap(LatLng point) {
    if (isTouchable) {
      _showPointDialog(point);
    }
  }

  void _showPointDialog(LatLng point) async {
    final String name = await _getAddressFromLatLng(point);
    print(name);
  }

  Future<String> _getAddressFromLatLng(LatLng point) async {
    final coordinates = new Coordinates(point.latitude, point.longitude);
    var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(
        coordinates);
    var first = address.first;
    String name = first.addressLine;
    return name;
  }

  void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    _mapController = controller;
    // _mapController.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
  }

  // method that adds the marker to the map
  _addMarker(LatLng position, String id, BitmapDescriptor descriptor,
      String info) {
    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(id);
    Marker marker =
    Marker(markerId: markerId,
        icon: descriptor,
        position: position,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: info
        ));
    markers[markerId] = marker;
  }



  // method that creates the polyline given the from and to geolocation
  _getPolyline(String name) async {
    List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      _googleAPiKey,
      _originLatitude,
      _originLongitude,
      _destLatitude,
      _destLongitude,);
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      result.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    }
    PolylineId id = PolylineId(name);
    Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        polylineId: id, color: Colors.blue, points: polylineCoordinates);
    polylines[id] = polyline;
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  _clearPolylines(){
    polylineCoordinates.clear();
    polylines.clear();
  }
  //
  // _clearMarkers() {
  //   markers.clear();
  // }



}
```

I tried all the possible ways. But i dont know why my code doesn't works.
I am a beginner. So please help me out. Is it necessary to create a link to my google account with billing for this. I think it was not necessary.

Comment: Thank You. I found out solution. I just changed my getMarkerData() function. I changed the above line " initMarker(myLocData.docs[i].data, myLocData.docs[i].id); " to "            initMarker(myLocData.docs[i].data(), myLocData.docs[i].id);"

Comment: could you post the solution you found as an answer? That way others in the community that go through the same issue may found the solution more easily.

Comment: sure..! I added my answer

Answer (score 1):

All I did in my code was correct. I was just mistyped the below word.

```
 getMarkerData() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').get().then((myLocData){
      if(myLocData.docs.isNotEmpty){
        for(int i=0;i<myLocData.docs.length;i++){
            //before initMarker(myLocData.docs[i].data, myLocData.docs[i].id);
            initMarker(myLocData.docs[i].data(), myLocData.docs[i].id); //after
        }
      }
    });
```